# Why will the power of signal become larger in the receiver ,but not smaller? the channel is a rayleigh fading channel

Tags: digital-communications

$\mathbf H_{AB}$ is a rayleigh fading ,$7$ is the antenna number for transmitting in the transmitter A, and $2$ is the antenna number for receiving in the receiver B

> H_{AB}=sqrt(1/2)*(randn(2,7), j * randn(2,7))

$\vec f^u_A$ is a $7$ by $1$ precoding direction,$(\vec f_A^{\ u})^H \vec f^u_A=1$

$p_A$ is a transmitted power of $\vec f_A$,assume $p_A=2.5W$,that is $\sqrt{p_A} \vec f^u_A=\vec f_A$

Now i sent the message from A to B,that is the SNR of receiver is

$SNR=\frac{| H_{AB} \  \vec f_A|^2}{N_0}=\frac{\vec f_A^ {\ H} H^H_{AB} \  \vec f_A \ H_{AB}} {N_0}=\frac{10W}{1W}=10$

I want to ask why will the received power be larger than the transmitted power ?

I think the power should decrease after going through the fading channel.where do i wrong?

Comment: Could you please give more detail how you came to the result 10W/1W ?

Comment: Also: recall that the Rayleigh channel only models small-scale fading. In a real setup you still have large-scale fading and shadowing, so the received power will always be a very small fraction of the transmitted power.